# RQT command does not display plugins after clean install

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am working with Ubuntu 16.04 and ros kinetic. I am trying to experiment with Ros QT for designing an interface for my project. I haven't been able to get the rqt command to display the plugins that I have installed.

I am a ROS newbie, so it is plausible that I made a mistake with how I installed rqt, but what I did was that I started with a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04, I followed the instructions listed here: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu and here http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment to verify ROS was installed correctly.

I then ran the commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

as instructed here http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/UserGuide/Install/Groovy

When I run the command

```
$rqt
```

I only get a blank window with no text.

I tried to verify that I had plugins installed by running

```
$ rqt --list-plugins
```

and I do get a populated list, and I can run the 'rqt_image_view' plugin directly from the command line.

My question is why do I not see any options to run plugins from the rqt window? Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286447/rqt-command-does-not-display-plugins-after-clean-install/) by [Coppermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/34294/coppermind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my 16.04 I see menus on the Ubuntu's top panel, not on `rqt`'s window (I think the default appearance changed sometimes between 14.04 and 16.04?).

Seems like you can change that setting on Ubuntu's level, see [this example](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-24**:
This could very well be the cause here.

**Comment by [Coppermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/34294/coppermind/) on 2018-03-24**:
This did turn out to be the issue, thank you for your help.

**Comment by [ishwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/49500/ishwar/) on 2019-11-17**:
This worked. Such a simple issue. Thanks a lot!!

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-01-06**:
what? I don"t understand what this means

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to run `rqt` with the `--force-discover` option. Some times a cache needs to be updated.

Related question: #q166851.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4